# NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription is not available in info.plist for iOS 13.5

Tags: ios, flutter, bluetooth

I am trying to build a flutter app using Bluetooth on a real device (iOS 13.6).
Build complete successful in Xcode and during transfer on the device, it give me this warning :

```
2020-10-25 09:19:51.696946+0100 Runner[14009:7499178] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

So I try to add missing key in info.plist and was not accepted (deprecated)

Question 1: device is iOS 13.6 and deployment info has only 13.5 or 13.7 -> what is the best choice, less or greater or any other version ?
Question 2: what to declare to allow my app to work with Bluetooth ?

Many thanks for your help and have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

[`NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsbluetoothalwaysusagedescription) is not deprecated. You need to add it.

`NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` is deprecated but you must still add it if you have a deployment target earlier than iOS 13 (so it is not required in your case).